# The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. - Wcf test client

Tags: wcf, service

I've developed a wcf service with basichttpbinding. I've hosted the service on web server. There is a load balancer which exposes this service through https url. When i try to access the endpoint address exposed via load balancer it throws error in wcf test client - "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'."
Below is the web.config configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>     
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="testServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application" suppressAuditFailure="false"
            serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="SuccessOrFailure" messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="SuccessOrFailure" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="testServiceBehavior" name="TestService">
        <endpoint address=""  binding="basicHttpBinding"
           contract="TestService.IService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to enable anonymous authentication in IIS:

[image]

If this value is set to Disable, the client needs to provide Windows identity information when calling.